# Merge three Variables to one and replicate observations

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have a Dataframe which looks like the following:

```
B <-  data.frame(
    nr=c(1,2,3,4,5),
    A=c('a','b','c','d','e'),
    B=c("s", "t", "i", "u", "z"),
    B1=c("", "v", "", "", ""),
    B2 =c("", "g", "", "", ""))
B <- B %>% mutate_all(na_if,"")
```

Since my Varaibales B1 and B2 only have one value, I would like to merge B1 and B2 to the Variable B. Therefor it should create two new observation and replicating every other Variable of this Oberservation.

It should look like the following:

```
B <-  data.frame(
    nr=c(1,2,2, 2, 3,4,5),
    A=c("a","b", "b", "b", "c","d","e"),
    B=c("s", "v", "g", "t", "i", "u", "z"))
```

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reshape to 'long' format with `pivot_longer` on the 'B' columns and remove the `NA` with `values_drop_na = TRUE`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
B %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("B"), values_to = "B", 
     values_drop_na = TRUE, names_to = NULL)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 7 × 3
     nr A     B    
  <dbl> <chr> <chr>
1     1 a     s    
2     2 b     t    
3     2 b     v    
4     2 b     g    
5     3 c     i    
6     4 d     u    
7     5 e     z
```